# Self hosting web application using Hostable Web Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, hostable-web-core

Am trying to host a web application (aspx web form) using hostable web core feature.

Using this when i tried to load the aspx page, am getting error

**error details :**

> responce : 502
>
> The connection to 'localhost' failed.  Error: ConnectionRefused
>   (0x274d).  System.Net.Sockets.SocketException No connection could be
>   made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8080

Then i changed the **CodeBehind** attribute to **CodeFile** , after that am getting this error :

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]
>   System.Web.HttpResponse.ApplyRedirectQueryStringIfRequired(String url)
>   +144    System.Web.HttpResponse.Redirect(String url, Boolean endResponse) +546
>   System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule.OnLeave(Object source,
>   EventArgs eventArgs) +1730
>   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +412    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +229

In the same application am having a test page in html format. When i tried to access that page, it's rendering properly.

Here am adding my configuration file also

[AppHostAspNet.config](https://drop.me/ogWjWo)

Comment: `hostable web core feature.` Are you not planing to host in IIS? Could you elaborate more?

Comment: due to lack of ArcGIS server license, for time being we are trying to host it as a self hosting application using HWC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some code changes and some configuration changes now it's working.

Here am attaching the working sample. [Sample](https://drop.me/MRNVlM)

In Program.cs change the code physical path

```
WebServer server = new WebServer( @"C:\project_path", port, siteId );
```